# Restoring data in dropbox using JAVA SDK

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

so i have ran into a small problem while designing an API which can restore data from the selected List check view from DropBox-

The checkList gets the List of deleted data and stores in another list called deletedItems ,so when the deleted data gets a selected over a checkList it is stored in deltedItems.

[image]

```
checkList = new ListView();
        Label labelresponse= new Label();
        checkList.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        checkList.setMaxHeight(400);
        checkList.setMaxWidth(280);
        checkList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        checkList.setCellFactory(CheckBoxListCell.forListView(new Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(String item) {
                BooleanProperty observable = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                observable.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasSelected, Boolean isNowSelected) -> {
                    //System.out.println("Check box for " + checkList+ " changed from " + wasSelected + " to " + isNowSelected);
                    if(isNowSelected) {
                        deletedItems.add(item);
                    }else{
                        deletedItems.remove(item);
                    }
                    System.out.println(deletedItems + "\n");
                    System.out.println(deletedItems.size() + "\n");
                    });
                observable.set(deletedItems.contains(item));
                deletedItems.addListener((SetChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) ->
                        observable.set(deletedItems.contains(item)));


                return observable ;
            }
        }));
```

Now i want method that will restore the the selected deletedItems. But i can't seem to implement it properly. I do found a java Code on how to Restore data in DropBox

```
public void dataRestoreFromList() throws DbxException {
        FileMetadata revision = revisions.get(0);
        revision.getRev();
        String rPath = revision.getPathLower();
        getDbxCleint().files().restore(rPath, revision.getRev());
    }
```

is there anyway i can restore the data from deletedItems Set using this method ?